# Django - update id of model referenced by a non-nullable foreign-key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a simple model. Let's say something similar to:

```
Person(id-uuid, name-string)
Dog(id-uuid, name-string, owner-ForeignKey(Person, null=False)
```

I have an instance of both of them: `p, d`

I want to change the id of the person `p`

The problem is that I can't change the if of the person `p` because it is being reference by `d`, and I can't change the reference of `d` since it's not nullable.

I don't think it matters, but I use either sqlite or postgres

Comment: Create duplicate of `p`, change `d` `FK` to new `p`, remove old `p`.

Comment: `I can't change the reference of d` you can't set it NULL.

Comment: This is the only idea I've got so far. Can't I just create something similar to a transaction where I'm allowed to break constraints just for a second before commiting it? Or letting django resolve it?

Comment: Don't want to be doing this on the fly, so I'd probably do it in a sequence of migrations: remove the null constraint; do the id and FK changes; replace the null constraint.